# Find the Latest Column From Text File Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that will allow me to document my earnings/spending's more efficiently, and I cannot seem to find how to find the latest column within a given text file, keep in mind the code is a prototype, as I only started working on it about an hour ago.

```
f = open('Money.txt','a')

while True:
    while True:
        OP = input("Operator: ")
        if OP == "+" or OP == "-":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Operator, please try again.\n\n")
    while True:
        try:
            MA = int(input("Money amount: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Numeric value only.\n\n")
    while True:
        if OP == "+":
            MV = input("Where you recived the money: ")
            break
        elif OP == "-":
           MV = input("Where you spent the money: ")
           break
    while True:
        C = input('\n\nIs "' + OP + "/" + str(MA) + "/" + MV + '" correct: ')
        if C.lower() == "yes":
            break
        elif C.lower() == "no":
            print("Restarting...\n\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid response, try again.\n\n")
    if C.lower() == "yes":
        break
    elif C.lower() == "no":
        continue

fs = OP + " $" + str(MA) + " / " + MV
f.write('\n' + fs)
f.close()
print("Values written.")

# "abcde!mdam!dskm".split("/", 2) - basic idea of the code ill use after i figure out how to get latest column from text file
```

I'm not too great at programming, so if you see a blatant way to improve my code, go ahead and share it, any help will be appriciated!

Comment: The code is on how to input data. Seems like you are adding new lines on every input. What do you mean by latest column?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified earlier, my document is arranged like: - $50 - Supermarket - (total amount of money left), and I want to find the previous total amount of money so that I can subtract/add depending on the operator to the amount of money left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, its probably not the most efficient method but it works:

```
fc = f.readlines()
l = -1
for line in fc:
    l += 1
```

You can then use "l" to slice your list and do whatever you need to do to it.

Note: You need to change the "f = open('Money2.txt','a')" to "f = open('Money2.txt','r+')"